# Is it possible to have a remote gradle.properties file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, parent-child, properties-file, parent-pom

I would like to have a remote `gradle.properties` (living on a server somewhere) that I am able to pull into my `build.gradle` and use.

Or if there is a good way to extend gradle like a parent pom for gradle... I looked for this method first but did not find any good/up to date results...

The idea is, if I have a lot of project that all need the same version I can update them all using one file. This way I will **not** have to pull each repository manually edit the file then commit changes and push...

If there is any other method that will solve this problem I am open to any solutions that are good practice. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use a [user-level](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file to share properties across projects?

Comment: @sschuberth This would require all developers who work with any of the projects to have this set in their user profiles. Each time a version needs to be updated all developers would then need to update their dev environments. This would be a pain to do, versions change all the time.  So to have one file that contains all the common versions would be ideal. One file to rule them all ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general Gradle configuration, you can create a custom plugin and publish it either internally or externally (Artifactory, Maven Central, etc).

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:init_script_plugins

For maintaining a consistent versions of dependencies (Maven dependency management BOM-like), then you'll want to create/publish a platform:

- Docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html
- JUnit example: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-bom/junit-bom.gradle.kts
- Published BOM: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/junit-bom/5.5.2/junit-bom-5.5.2.pom

Answer (score 1):

A viable solution is to fetch a configuration file by http in **Project.beforeEvaluate()** or in **Project.configurations()** and populate the project configurations with its content. Though the file name doesn't has to be gradle.properties.